# Prevent Silverlight ListBox vertical scrollbar from being displayed

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-2-rc0

I have a ListBox which displays items of variable height. I want to show as many items as will fit in the available space, without showing a vertical scrollbar. Other than surgery on the ListBox item template, is there a way to only show the number of items which will fit without scrolling?

Comment: Does Silverlight not have ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollbarVisibility, Jon?

Comment: Matt, I wish you'd added that as an answer so I could have voted for you...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
 <ListBox ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

the default is visible

Answer (score 3):

I don't think the default is "Visible". I think it's "Auto". Jon wanted to set it to "Hidden".